# JQuery on change event is not working inside popup

Tags: jquery, events, popup

I'm using simple event but is not working on change inside popup

I have tried even give script tag inside model but its still not working even not console the checked element. Please let me know what i am doing wrong i don't think so there is something wrong. I have tried onchange tag as well

```js
$(function() {
  // Working checked
  $('body').on('change', '[data-type=Working]', function() {
    var E = $(this).prop('checked') == true ? true : false;
   $('body').on('change','[data-type=Working]',function(){
  var E = $(this).prop('checked');
   if(E){
     $('[data-type=EndDateMonth]').hide();
  }else{
      $('[data-type=EndDateMonth]').show();
   }
 });
 $('[data-type=Working]:checked').change();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="post">
  <div class="uk-modal" id="Experiences">
    <div class="uk-modal-dialog">
      <div class="uk-modal-header">
        <h3 class="uk-modal-title">Add Experiences</h3>
      </div>
      <div data-type="Fields" class="uk-grid uk-grid-width-large-1-2 uk-grid-width-xlarge-1-4" data-uk-grid-margin>
        <div class="uk-width-medium-1-2">
          <div class="parsley-row">
            <label for="Company">Company Name</label>
            <input class="md-input" required name="Company" value="" type="text" />
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="uk-width-medium-1-2">
          <div class="parsley-row">
            <label for="Designation">Designation</label>
            <input class="md-input" required name="Designation" value="" type="text" />
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="uk-width-medium-1-1">
          <div class="parsley-row">
            <label for="Config[CategoryID]">Category</label>
            <select class="md-input" data-type="Category" required name="Config[CategoryID]">
              <option value="0">Select...</option>
              <option value="1">Cat 1</option>
              <option value="2">Sub 2</option>
            </select>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="uk-width-medium-1-2">
          <div class="parsley-row">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="uk-width-medium-1-2">
          <div class="parsley-row">
            <label for="Salary">Current Salary</label>
            <input class="md-input" data-type="Salary" required name="Salary" value="" type="text" />
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="uk-width-medium-1-2">
          <div class="parsley-row">
            <label for="Config[CountryID]">Location</label>
            <select class="md-input" data-type="Country" required name="Config[CountryID]">
              <option value="0">Select...</option>
              <option value="1">Pakistan</option>
              <option value="2">Africa</option>
            </select>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="uk-width-medium-1-2">
          <div class="parsley-row">
            <label for="Config[CityID]"></label>
            <select class="md-input" data-type="City" required name="Config[CityID]">
              <option value="0">Select City</option>
            </select>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="uk-width-medium-1-2">
          <div class="parsley-row">
            <label for="Config[TimeStart]">Start Date</label>
            <input class="md-input" data-type="StartDateMonth" required name="Config[TimeStart]" value="" type="text" />
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="uk-width-medium-1-2">
          <div class="parsley-row">
            <label for="Config[TimeEnd]">End Date</label>
            <input class="md-input" data-type="EndDateMonth" name="Config[TimeEnd]" value="" type="text" />
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class='uk-width-medium-1-1 uk-row-first'>
          <div class='parsley-row'>
            <label>Currently Working or Not</label>
            <div class='md-input-wrapper'>
              <span class="icheck-inline"> <input data-md-icheck data-type="Working" id="1" name="Currently" value="1" type="checkbox"/> <label for="Currently Working" class="inline-label">Currently Working</label></span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="uk-width-medium-1-1">
          <div class="parsley-row">
            <label for="Config[Description]">Description</label>
            <textarea class="md-input" name="Config[Description]"></textarea>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div data-type="Result"></div>
      <div class="uk-modal-footer uk-text-right"><button class="md-btn md-btn-success md-btn-wave-light waves-effect waves-button waves-light" name="Submit">Submit</button><button type="button" data-dismiss="modal" class="md-btn md-btn-flat uk-modal-close" name="Close">Close</button></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

I'm using script tag inside footer area jquery library as well.

Comment: Firstly, `var E = $(this).prop('checked') == true ? true : false;` should just be `var E = $(this).prop('checked')`. Secondly, `E` is a boolean, it has no `val()`, so I'm not sure what you're expecting this to do: `if (E.val() == true) {`. Perhaps just `if (E) {`...?

Comment: i have done this changes as well but its not fixed yet

Comment: because i don't think so this is an issue

Comment: i'm using script tag inside body in footer area

Answer (score 0):

Firstly note that `.prop('checked')` returns a boolean, so the ternary expression is redundant.

Secondly, a boolean has no `val()` method; you seem to be confusing it with a jQuery object. You can simply use the `E` variable directly in the `if` condition. You can also provide that boolean value to `toggle()` to remove the need for separate `show()` and `hide()` calls.

Finally note that `E` isn't a good variable name. They should describe the value they hold. With all that said, try this:

```js
$(function() {
  // Working checked
  $('body').on('change', '[data-type="Working"]', function() {
    var isChecked = $(this).prop('checked');
    $('[data-type="EndDateMonth"]').toggle(!isChecked);
  });
  
  $('[data-type="Working"]:checked').change();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="post">
  <div class="uk-modal" id="Experiences">
    <div class="uk-modal-dialog">
      <div class="uk-modal-header">
        <h3 class="uk-modal-title">Add Experiences</h3>
      </div>
      <div data-type="Fields" class="uk-grid uk-grid-width-large-1-2 uk-grid-width-xlarge-1-4" data-uk-grid-margin>
        <div class="uk-width-medium-1-2">
          <div class="parsley-row">
            <label for="Company">Company Name</label>
            <input class="md-input" required name="Company" value="" type="text" />
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="uk-width-medium-1-2">
          <div class="parsley-row">
            <label for="Designation">Designation</label>
            <input class="md-input" required name="Designation" value="" type="text" />
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="uk-width-medium-1-1">
          <div class="parsley-row">
            <label for="Config[CategoryID]">Category</label>
            <select class="md-input" data-type="Category" required name="Config[CategoryID]">
              <option value="0">Select...</option>
              <option value="1">Cat 1</option>
              <option value="2">Sub 2</option>
            </select>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="uk-width-medium-1-2">
          <div class="parsley-row">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="uk-width-medium-1-2">
          <div class="parsley-row">
            <label for="Salary">Current Salary</label>
            <input class="md-input" data-type="Salary" required name="Salary" value="" type="text" />
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="uk-width-medium-1-2">
          <div class="parsley-row">
            <label for="Config[CountryID]">Location</label>
            <select class="md-input" data-type="Country" required name="Config[CountryID]">
              <option value="0">Select...</option>
              <option value="1">Pakistan</option>
              <option value="2">Africa</option>
            </select>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="uk-width-medium-1-2">
          <div class="parsley-row">
            <label for="Config[CityID]"></label>
            <select class="md-input" data-type="City" required name="Config[CityID]">
              <option value="0">Select City</option>
            </select>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="uk-width-medium-1-2">
          <div class="parsley-row">
            <label for="Config[TimeStart]">Start Date</label>
            <input class="md-input" data-type="StartDateMonth" required name="Config[TimeStart]" value="" type="text" />
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="uk-width-medium-1-2">
          <div class="parsley-row">
            <label for="Config[TimeEnd]">End Date</label>
            <input class="md-input" data-type="EndDateMonth" name="Config[TimeEnd]" value="" type="text" />
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class='uk-width-medium-1-1 uk-row-first'>
          <div class='parsley-row'>
            <label>Currently Working or Not</label>
            <div class='md-input-wrapper'>
              <span class="icheck-inline"> <input data-md-icheck data-type="Working" id="1" name="Currently" value="1" type="checkbox"/> <label for="Currently Working" class="inline-label">Currently Working</label></span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="uk-width-medium-1-1">
          <div class="parsley-row">
            <label for="Config[Description]">Description</label>
            <textarea class="md-input" name="Config[Description]"></textarea>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div data-type="Result"></div>
      <div class="uk-modal-footer uk-text-right"><button class="md-btn md-btn-success md-btn-wave-light waves-effect waves-button waves-light" name="Submit">Submit</button><button type="button" data-dismiss="modal" class="md-btn md-btn-flat uk-modal-close" name="Close">Close</button></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: not working even alert is also not working 

$('body').on('change', '[data-type=Working]', function() {
       alert('hamza');
          var isChecked = $(this).prop('checked');
          $('[data-type=EndDateMonth]').toggle(!isChecked);
      });
         $('[data-type=Working]:checked').change();

Comment: In which case please update the question to more accurately reflect the HTML and JS you use. As you can see from the snippet above, based on the code in the question this works fine. Also, check the console for errors